# Printing in order with c threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Given this code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

void *findPrimes(void *arg)
{
    int val = *(int *)arg;
    for (int i = val * 1000; i < val * 1000 + 1000; i++)
    {
        int isPrime = 1;
        for (int j = 2; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0)
            {
                isPrime = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime)
        {
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
int main()
{
    pthread_t p[3];

    int val[3] = {0, 1, 2};
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&p[i], NULL, findPrimes, &val[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(p[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Who prints in 3 threads all the prime number between 0 and 3000.

I want to print them in order, how can i do it?
My professor suggest to use an array of semaphore.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have tried to solve the problem together with my colleagues and revisiting the subject several times. I also asked the professor for a clue, and he told me what I wrote. I went through a lot of online slides and stack overflow questions but nothing.
Being an optional question, the professor will not provide the solution.
I just needed to figure out if it was feasible first and how to implement it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil True, but the prof. suggested semaphores which isn't what I'd use. I'd go for a mutex and condition variable.

Comment: @LucaPedersoli: That is very nice, you have explained why you have a problem and why it is a bit beyond your course materials. But it is still not a suitable question for Stack Overflow. Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site. It is for specific, narrow questions, not for teaching things that are thoroughly documented in textbooks and elsewhere. There are other resources on the web and in libraries for teaching about synchronization. Turn to those, not to Stack Overflow.

Comment: I might use `num_threads - 1` semaphores, but not just one for three threads.  Mutex + CV is of course the Swiss Army Knife of thread coordination, and that would work fine here (in conjunction with a shared variable).

Comment: Of course, that assumes one is not allowed to just run the three workloads serially, in the initial thread, which would be better in almost every way.

Comment: Oh well, I came back now and the question wasn't closed yet so I provided one possible solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to synchronize the actions of all the threads I suggest using a [`pthread_mutex_t`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html) and a [`pthread_cond_t`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_timedwait.html) (a *condition variable*). You also need a way to share data between threads, so I'd create a `struct` for that:

```c
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned whos_turn;
    pthread_mutex_t mtx;
    pthread_cond_t cv;
} shared_data;
```

`whos_turn` will here be used to tell the threads whos turn it is to print the primes found.

Each thread also needs some thread-unique information. You called it `val` so I'll call it `val` here too. We can compare `val` with `whos_turn` to decide which thread it is that should print its result. In order to pass both the shared data and `val` to a thread, you can package that in a `struct` too:

```c
typedef struct {
    unsigned val;
    shared_data *sd; // will point to the one and only instance of `shared_data`
} work_order;
```

Now, `findPrimes` need somewhere to store the primes it calculates before it's time to print them. Since the range to search is hardcoded, I'd just add an array for that:

```c
#define SEARCH_RANGE (1000ULL)

void *findPrimes(void *arg) {
    work_order *wo = arg;
    
    uintmax_t primes[SEARCH_RANGE]; // to store the found primes
    int found_count = 0;
    
    for (uintmax_t i = wo->val*SEARCH_RANGE+1; i <= (wo->val+1)*SEARCH_RANGE; i += 2) {
        bool isPrime = true;
        for (uintmax_t j = 3; j < i; j += 2) {
            if (i % j == 0) {    // note: both i and j are odd
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime) {
            primes[found_count++] = i;
        }
    }
    if(wo->val == 0) {  // special case for the first range
        primes[0] = 2;  // 1 is not a prime, but 2 is.
    }
    // ... to be continued below ...
```

So far, nothing spectacular. The thread has now found all primes in its range and has come to the synchronizing part. The thread must

- lock the mutex
- wait for its turn (called "the predicate")
- let other threads do the same

Here's one common pattern:

```c
    // ... continued from above ...

    // synchronize
    pthread_mutex_lock(&wo->sd->mtx);      // lock the mutex
    // only 1 thread at a time reaches here
    // check the predicate: That is's this thread's turn to print
    while(wo->val != wo->sd->whos_turn) {  // <- the predicate
        // if control enters here, it was not this thread's turn

        // cond_wait internally "unlocks" the mutex to let other threads
        // reach here and wait for the condition variable to get signalled
        pthread_cond_wait(&wo->sd->cv, &wo->sd->mtx);

        // and here the lock is only held by one thread at a time again
    }
    // only the thread whos turn it is reaches here
```

Now, the thread has reached the point where it is its time to print. It has the mutex lock so no other threads can reach this point at the same time.

```
    // print the collected primes
    for(int i = 0; i < found_count; ++i)
        printf("%ju\n", primes[i]);
```

And hand over to the next thread in line to print the primes it has found:

```
    // step the "whos_turn" indicator
    wo->sd->whos_turn++;

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&wo->sd->mtx);  // release the mutex
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&wo->sd->cv); // signal all threads to check the predicate
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

And it can be tied together quite neatly in `main`:

```
#define Size(x) (sizeof (x) / sizeof *(x))

int main() {
    shared_data sd = {.whos_turn = 0,
                      .mtx = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER,
                      .cv = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER};
    pthread_t p[3];
    
    work_order wos[Size(p)];

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < Size(p); i++) {
        wos[i].val = i;  // the thread-unique information
        wos[i].sd = &sd; // all threads will point at the same `shared_data`
        pthread_create(&p[i], NULL, findPrimes, &wos[i]);
    }
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < Size(p); i++) {
        pthread_join(p[i], NULL);
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/WdEY1EME9)